# Connect-mongo Syntax Error: unexpected token =>

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, connect-mongo

Hi I have the following error

```
node_modules/connect-mongo/src/index.js:29
unserialize: options.unserialize || (x => x),
^^
```

I have these versions:

node@v3.3.1

express@4.14.0

mongoose@4.6.5

mongodb@2.2.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you have an outdated version of Node.js.

The `(x => x)` is equivalent with `function (x) { return x; }` (it's called an arrow function).

Update Node.js to a version greater than `4.0.0`.

Running the `node` process with the `--harmony` flag could solve the issue, but still updating the Node.js to a recent version is much better.

Comment: I did this but no difference:
`sudo npm cache clean -f

sudo npm install -g n

sudo n stable`

Comment: What does `node --version` output?

Comment: Output: └─── n@2.1.4

Comment: Hmm, just run `node --version`. It should output something like `v....`

Comment: Yes, just download a recent version from [the Node.js website](https://nodejs.org/en/)––probably the LTS one.